# What's wrong with my FormulaLocal syntax?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vba to insert a formula into cell `A67` on my Sheet. I believe it can be done with the formula I have below, but unfortunately I do not know how to fix my syntax below.

The sheet I am trying to pull from is `RD1` through `RD35` depending on circumstances.

i is my variable defined as 1 to 35

Do you know why RD & i does not define my sheet properly? Did i miss a quotation mark?

`Range("A67").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=Vlookup(large(RD & i!B2:B100,1),RD & i!B2:E100,4,false)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Range("A67").Select ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=Vlookup(large(RD & i!B2:B100,1),RD & i!B2:E100,4,false)"
```

is a string and so to insert variables into the string you must close your quotes out insert the variable then continue the string.

your line should be:
should be:

```
Range("A67").Select ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=Vlookup(large(RD" & i & "!B2:B100,1),RD" & i & "!B2:E100,4,false)"
```